# How to add setbinding for Label using Object Initializer in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, label, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to use **set binding** within the label using object initializer in Xamarin Forms

```
a) Label lb = new Label();
   lb.setBinding(----);


b) new Label{
**Set Binding** ???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you can't use [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to set the binding of Controls.

Because ([definition from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)): 
*Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.*

You can't use [SetBinding](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/System.String/) in Object initilaizer because its not a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) or an accessible field, but a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

You have to use SetBinding as follows :

```
var label = new Label ();
label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Name");
label.BindingContext = new {Name = "John Doe", Company = "Xamarin"};
```